Proof of the General Change of Variables Theorem in Rn?
I was reading the theroems on site https://planetmath.org/changeofvariablesinintegralonmathbbrn and found the following general change of variables theorem:
Theorem 2. Let g:X→Rn be continuously differentiable on an open subset X of Rn. Then for any measurable function f:Y→R, and any measurable set E⊆X,$$\int_E f(g(x)) \cdot |\; \mbox{det} \; Dg(x)| \, dx = \int_{g(E)} f(y) \cdot \#g_{|_E}^{-1}(y) \, dy,$$
where $\#g_{|_E}^{-1}(y)$∈{1,2,…,∞} counts the number of pre-images in E of y.
But, unfortunately, there is no demonstration of this result on this website. I was also unable to find the proof of this Theorem 2 in any of the references given. So where can I find this proof?

Please use MathJax to ask questions.

I'm not used to mathjax yet, but, regardless, the question is understandable

It is a convention on this site, and if you are interested in this level of mathematics, well worth the effort. You can look at other questions and see how they are formatted.

At some point I'll definitely check that

Have you looked at the references that the website cites at the bottom of the page?

Yes. They are very useful as references for Theorem 1 that appears there, but none of them, as far as I checked, have a proof of the second theorem

After a long search I found the demonstration of this theorem, with stronger hypotheses, in the following reference:
[1] Bojarski, Bogdan, and Tadeusz Iwaniec. "Analytical foundations of the theory of quasiconformal mappings in Rn." Annales Fennici Mathematici 8.2 (1983): 257-324. (Theorem 8.4.)
And I also found a weaker version of this theorem at:
[2] Hajłasz, Piotr. "Change of variables formula under minimal assumptions." Colloquium Mathematicae. Vol. 64. No. 1. 1993.
However, I still haven't been able to find a demonstration for this result with the same hypotheses as planetmath (which has the most general hypotheses I've seen for this result, which for example is cited in the book - Linear and Nonlinear Functional Analysis with Applications, page 34).
